# Deleting first cell in Excel using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that generates an excel table with a lot of numbers but I do not need the first cell in column A so I want a script that deletes the first cell in column A automatically after the Excel list is created

this is the script which generates the Excel table

```
$re = [regex]'ixi:\+49.*(\d{4})'    
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses |  
  Select-Object @{Name = 'ixi'; Expression = {$re.Match($_.ProxyAddresses).Groups[1].Value}} | Where-Object { $_.ixi.Trim() } | export-csv C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup10.csv -Delimiter ";" -notypeinformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Comment: Why just don't fill the column A initially?

Comment: thank you for the reply, if i understand what you mean exactly the reason would be because the first cell in column A has to be free and it's content is not needed

Comment: I mean why not just omit this cell when you generate the table?

Comment: oh you mean in the table itself after generating it..., it has to be done automatically by powrshell, it's the whole point of my homework

Comment: What @montonero means is do something like: `Select-Object @{Name = 'A'; Expression = {$null}}, @{Name = 'ixi'; Expression = {$re.Match($_.ProxyAddresses).Groups[1].Value}}`

Comment: oh i didn't really understand that, i'm still a noob..,                                                            Thank you for clearing that to me